# mysql sequence event not functioning correctly!

Tags: php, mysql, events, scheduled-tasks

I've created a mysql scheduled event in order to increment a row value by 1 every 5 seconds. However instead of the desired behavior, the value is incremented wildly in excess of 1.  I have checked phpMyAdmin and there appears to be no duplicate events operating on the row.

```
// creats event which auto increment picture_select
$sql = "SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1";
mysql_query($sql, $connection)
    or die(mysql_error()); 


$sql = "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS picture_increment
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
DO
UPDATE pictures SET picture_select = picture_select+1 WHERE picture_id = '1'";
$create_event = mysql_query($sql, $connection)
    or die(mysql_error());
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

IF NOT EXISTS can cause problems (where basically it doesn't always work) and ends up starting up many multiple threads all doing the same thing, in your case it may be causing picture_id to increment wildly. Check your event logs to see if this is your problem